# SSH Tunnel not working, but not able to find the point of failure as it worked previously

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, ssh-tunnel

I am having an odd issue wherein suddenly port forwarding stopped working in a particular scenario for me.  By default I need a particular port forwarded on all servers I manage and so I have the following in my ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host *
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath /tmp/%r@%h:%p
    ServerAliveInterval 120
    ServerAliveCountMax 3

    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes

    RemoteForward 52698 127.0.0.1:52698
```

I then initiate ssh to the server (`ssh username@server.tld`) and query my local workstation to make sure that there are listeners for port 52698; `sudo lsof -i -P | grep 52698`:

```
AppName   40262        username   45u  IPv6 0x4b497d2de68055a1      0t0    TCP *:52698 (LISTEN)
sshd      92207        username   14u  IPv6 0x4b497d2d9e7ec4a1      0t0    TCP localhost:52698 (LISTEN)
sshd      92207        username   15u  IPv4 0x4b497d2dbb985641      0t0    TCP localhost:52698 (LISTEN)
```

I then likewise make sure that the port is active on the server, `lsof -P | grep 52698`:

```
sshd      16366      root    7u     IPv6             196798        0t0        TCP localhost:52698 (LISTEN)
sshd      16366      root    8u     IPv4             196799        0t0        TCP localhost:52698 (LISTEN)
```

I am not sure what may have provoked this to stop working.  I have tried several Internet connections from various ISPs and VPNs to no avail in terms of getting past this, so I have to assume that this is a local issue to my workstation and the connection to the server, but I'm not seeing a solution or exactly where to look in order to find out what might be going on here.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: On the remote server the application that tunnels data back to my workstation is not working.  It is a ruby script that is simply failing to use the tunnel to get the information over when I specify a port.